# Get dropdown's value with $(this)

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get value from dropdown box but it won't work.

```
function izaberiJezik()
{
    alert($(this).val());

}

<select onchange="izaberiJezik()" style="max-width:150px">
    <option value="-">Language</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="hr">Hrvatski</option>
</select>
```

I would like to use $(this) because I have 2 the same select boxes on a page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass `this` to your `onchange` function to get a reference to targeted `select`:

```
<select onchange="izaberiJezik(this)" style="max-width:150px">
```

then you can use:

```
function izaberiJezik(el)
{
    alert(el.value);
}
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ndd4r/)**

For jQuery approach, you can use **[.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/)** event handler:

```
$('select').change(function() {
    alert(this.value);
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ndd4r/2/)**

Comment: While it works, it is better not to use inline event listener.

Comment: Well, partially works, I believe. I do not think `<select>` has a proper `.value` in older Internet Explorer versions (8 and below). Since the poster already utilizes jQuery, you better just use it, which takes care of the `.value` issue.

Comment: I used that and just added alert($(el).val()); I've never knew I had to pass "this"

Answer (score 5):

I would use a proper event handler:

```
<select id="language" style="max-width:150px">
    <option value="-">Language</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="hr">Hrvatski</option>
</select>

$('#language').on('change', function() {
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Might want to use a class instead of an id since OP has two of the same `select`s.

Answer (score 2):

First,  its not a great idea to bind all your change events inline.  Utilize the features of jQuery and bind in the document ready.

HTML

```
<select id="myselect" style="max-width:150px">
    <option value="-">Language</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="hr">Hrvatski</option>
</select>

<select id="mysecondSelect" style="max-width:150px">
    <option value="-">Language</option>
    <option value="en">English</option>
    <option value="hr">Hrvatski</option>
</select>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("#myselect, #mysecondSelect").on("change", function(evt) {
      alert($(this).val());
   });
})
```

Here is a demo http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Sp8/1/